# No data table with Python3 Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to improve this script to extract daily data from this site. However, I am not getting any data except for the "Spot" column!
Thanks for the help!

UPD. Now i can't change the date(

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url ="https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/natural-gas/spot"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver1/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/natural-gas/spot")
time.sleep(10)
date_picker = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="symbolheader_ngs"]/div/div/div/input')))
date_picker.send_keys("2023-01-23")
time.sleep(20)

page_source = browser.page_source
s = bs(page_source)

table = s.select('table')[1]

final_list = []
for row in table.select('tr'):
   final_list.append([x.text for x in row.find_all(['td', 'th'])])
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list[2:], columns = final_list[:1])
final_df.columns = ['Spot', 'Last Price', 'Last Volume', 'End of Day Index', 'Volume Exchange','del']
df=final_df.drop('del',axis=1)

browser.quit()

df.to_excel('final_df.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

little tweaks so that all columns can be extracted. main idea is that extract logic need to be checked with how HTML dom is.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

def get_df(page_source):
    soup = bs(page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.select('table')[1]
    table_header=table.find("tr", {"class": "mv-quote-header-row"})
    table_body=table.select('tbody')
    result={}


    for e_header in table_header.find_all('th'):
        if e_header.text:
            result[e_header.text]=[]
    for e_r in table_body[0].find_all('tr'):
        r1=[e.text for e in e_r.find_all('td',{'class':not ['mv-quote-button']})]
        result['Spot'].append(r1[0])
        result['Last Price'].append(r1[1])
        result['Last Volume'].append(r1[2])
        result['End of Day Index'].append(r1[3])
        result['Volume Exchange'].append(r1[4])
    #result
    df=pd.DataFrame(result)
    return df


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
#webdriver_service = Service()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/natural-gas/spot")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html5lib')

page_source=browser.page_source

#table = soup.select('table')[1]
final_df=get_df(browser.page_source)
browser.quit()
final_df.to_excel('final_df.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: thanks, but i have trouble `MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=51125)`

Comment: which line throwing that error?

Comment: my mistake, when i copied code :( , `browser.quit()` at wrong place. fixed, and should work now.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. But I get a table with no data. Even adding something like `driver.implicitly_wait` doesn't work. Can a site block Selenium?

Comment: still works okay for me. does it open URL and are you seeing the table on the web page? if blocked, you will see some message on web page.

Comment: working!
But now i can't change the date on the web site
I change my question

Comment: when you are debugging, pls comment the `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` so you know if selenium is working well or not. in this case, site does not have data for 01/23, so try with 01/20 - `2023-01-20`, so your new three lines would be `date_picker = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="symbolheader_ngs"]/div/div/div/input')))
date_picker.clear()
date_picker.send_keys("2023-01-20")`